# Postgres - Select all if given parameter is null

Tags: postgresql

i have a table with the below columns

```
name varchar(250)
type varchar(25)
```

is there a way for me to structure a query to return all records if the type parameter is null?

Im aware that i can do something like

```
select * from tbl where type = Coalesce(@param, 'a');
```

which will give me all records of type 'a' if i give an empty param.

But what if i want to retrieve all records if param is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the placeholder for strings:

```
select * from tbl where type LIKE Coalesce(@param, '%');
```

Comment: Using `like` will slow down the query a lot.

Comment: no, all rdms have optimized algorithms for string comparison LIKE and = have the same speed

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd construct the query in the application, adding only those parameters that the user has specified.

Failing that, try something like this:

```
select field1, field2, field3, ... 
from table1 
where ( type = @param or @param is null )
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is simple**. You can use **coalesce** on the where clause itself.

```
select * from tbl where coalesce(type = 'your_query', true);
```